# How to redirect one domain to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have two domains:

```
www.example1.com/ --> IP=1.2.3.4
www.example2.com/ --> IP=1.2.3.4 (same IP for both domains)
```

I want all requests that go to `www.example2.com/*` to access the requested page.
I want all requests that go to `www.example1.com/*` to redirect to `www.example2.com/*`. How would I do this in apache? As now I am currently doing this in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you -- is this in the same directory as my `apache2.conf` file?

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is defined in `apache2.conf` and is usually not same. It is something like `/var/www` or something like this. Just search for `DocumentRoot` in your `apache2.conf` file.