# Redirection of domain within <VirtualHost> tag

Tags: regex, apache2, httpd.conf

I have the following in my apache2.conf file for a django project:

```
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/Avails/static
    # virtual host configuration
    WSGIScriptAlias / home/ubuntu/Avails/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Similar to a previous question I asked here ([How to redirect one domain to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24619550/how-to-redirect-one-domain-to-another)).

I have two domains:

```
www.new.example1.com/ --> IP=1.2.3.4
www.new.example2.com/ --> IP=1.2.3.4 (same IP for both domains)
```

I want all requests that go to www.example2.com/* to access the requested page. I want     all requests that go to www.example1.com/* to redirect to www.example2.com/*. how would I redirect a domain **within the VirtualHost block**, instead of using the .htaccess file?

Comment: Same code that I suggested on that thread can be used here also.

Comment: Thank you -- do I need to add in the `RewriteEngine On` line as well? Or only the RewriteCond and RewriteRule lines?

Comment: You will need `RewriteEngine On` line also

Comment: [You can't use `RewriteCond` or `RewriteRule` without switching on the `RewriteEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine).

Comment: I get the following error: `Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. How do I specify this module in my server configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked. Special thanks to anubhava for the help:

1) Enable module rewrite:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

2) Edit apache2.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/Avails/static
    # virtual host configuration
    WSGIScriptAlias / home/ubuntu/Avails/wsgi.py
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.example1\.net [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://new.example2.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Restart apache:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```